# How to detect when 'Home ad" from AdMob is displaying?

Tags: android, admob

I wonder how to display ads from MobClix when AdMob has nothing to offer and want to display the Home Ad.
I think about two ways:
First:

```
@Override
public void onReceiveAd(Ad arg0)
{
    if(HomeAd) 
    {
          //I hide Home Ad and run MobClix service
    }   
}
```

Second:

```
@Override
public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad ad, AdRequest.ErrorCode errorCode)
{
  if (errorCode.NO_FILL)
  {
        //I hide Home Ad and run MobClix service
  }
}
```

First: There's something like "if(HomeAd)" ?
Second: I don't know when "errorCode.NO_FILL" is exactly running ? When there isn't ANY ads to display or there isn't paid ads to display.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a mediation solution such as [Adwhirl](https://www.adwhirl.com/).  You can configure which ad networks you want to request ads from as well as prioritize the backfill order when the initial ad network has no ad to show.